# Find bug on below semaphore implementation using monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, semaphore

In an interview was asked to identify bug in the below code , if there is any.
Below class implements semaphore with certain capacity.

```
    public class MySemaphore
    {
        private object _mutex = new object();
        private int _currAvail;

        public MySemaphore(int capacity)
        {
            _currAvail​ = capacity;
        }

        public void Wait()
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (_currAvail == 0) Monitor.Wait(_mutex);
                _currAvail--;
            }
        }

        public void Signal()
        {
            lock (_mutex) {
                _currAvail​++;
                Monitor.Pulse(_mutex);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the expected/desirable behavior, and what is the actual/buggy behavior of this code?

Comment: In an interview I was asked to find bug in the code, if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: I don't use C#. I am not familiar with `Monitor.Wait(o)` and `Monitor.Pulse(o)`, but I believe that  `_currAvail` could go negative if two or more threads are allowed to simultaneously call `sema.Wait()`.

Suppose that thread A and thread C concurrently call `sema.Wait()` while thread B calls `sema.Signal()`. Here's what I think could happen:

```text
currAvail  mutex   Thread A       Thread B        Thread C
---------  -----   -------------  --------------  --------------
    0      free    lock(mutex)         .               .
    0        A     Await Pulse()  Await mutex          .
    0      free      ''    ''     lock(mutex)          .
    0        B       ''    ''     currAvail++     Await mutex
    1        B       ''    ''     Pulse()          ''    ''

    1        B     Await mutex    release(mutex)   ''    ''
    1      free      ''    ''          .          lock(mutex)
    1        C       ''    ''          .          curAvail--
    0        C       ''    ''          .          release(mutex)
    0      free      ''    ''          .               .

    0      free    lock(mutex)         .               .
    0        A     currAvail--         .               .
   -1        A     release(mutex)      .               .
   -1      free          .             .               .
```

The fix is to re-check `_currAvail` after `Monitor.Wait(_mutex)` returns. I.e., call `Monitor.Wait(_mutex)` in a loop:

```C#
lock (_mutex) {
    while (_currAvail == 0) Monitor.Wait(_mutex);
    _currAvail--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with this Semaphore that I can see:

- `capacity` is actually just initial capacity, not a total capacity. Therefore one can just call `Signal` 1000 times and have 1000 additional capacity.
- integer overflow is not handled. If you put `int.MaxValue` as the initial capacity and then `Signal`, your current capacity will be at `int.MinValue`.
- the constructor doesn't check if the passed-in int is negative

Comment: Re, "capacity..." Could be a "bug" or could be just a poorly chosen name for the constructor argument. Can't say without talking about what the constructor argument is _supposed_ to mean. And, "talking about..." is (or _should be_) the whole point of the exercise. When I've asked job candidates questions like this one, I was never looking for a "correct" answer. I always was trying to start a dialogue in which the candidate could show me something of how they thought about programming problems.